# performSelector for static methods with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, uicolor

I am porting some Obj-C code and trying to do the Swift equivalent of :

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(value);

BOOL isColorMethod = [[UIColor class] respondsToSelector:selector];

if(isColorMethod) {

  UIColor *color = [[UIColor class] performSelector:selector];
}
```

I've done some research and all I can find are posts suggesting I create a dictionary of the method names with instances of each color object. This seems very unnecessary and I am pulling the color names (redColor for example) from a plist because I'm building a simple StyleManager so they have to be Strings.

Anyone know how you do this in Swift 2?

EDIT

It seems I was authoring Swift 1 after all. This doesn't work in 1. It seems I should have known this. I'm just going to go and flog myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it exactly as you have it:

```
let s = Selector("redColor")
let color = UIColor.performSelector(s)
```

The only problem is that you have to add memory management. So:

```
let s = Selector("redColor")
let color = UIColor.performSelector(s).takeRetainedValue()
```

And with your `responds` check added:

```
let s = Selector("redColor")
if UIColor.respondsToSelector(s) {
    let color = UIColor.performSelector(s).takeRetainedValue()
}
```

Added screen shot for benefit of Doubting Thomas:

[image]

**EDIT** MartinR says that where I have `takeRetainedValue()` you should put `takeUnretainedValue()`. And I have no idea, so I'm perfectly willing to believe that!

Comment: I did try this but it complains about UIColor.performSelector ... let me take a look again ...

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. 'performSelector' is unavailable.

Comment: There's performSelectorOnMainThread(selector:, withObject:) etc but I can't see how you would use this for a static.

Comment: @LeeProbert I didn't just write that code down out of my head. I developed it first. I assure you it does run, and it gives the right answer.

Comment: Added screen shot showing the app actually running and giving the correct answer in the console.

Comment: I believe you dude. I think it must be a Swift 2 thing. What version are you running?

Comment: You said you were using Swift 2. Look at your question. "Anyone know how you do this in Swift 2?" That's what you asked so that's what I answered. Naturally in Swift 1 it's a completely different matter; in fact, it would be basically impossible. You'd have to use the solution you've already mentioned, a dictionary of names and closures. But then, if you have not upgraded to the latest version (Xcode 7.1, Swift 2.1) you have to expect to be left behind.

Comment: Yes. My bad. I'm running 6.4. Thanks for the help.

Comment: BTW, if you insist on staying with Xcode 6.4, then your best bet might be to write just this part of your code in Objective-C. My Swift 1.2 code was full of little Objective-C "helper" code snippets, to get past Swift limitations. My Swift 2 code, however, is not; everything I need to do is now doable in pure Swift.

Comment: I am fairly sure that it should be `takeUnretainedValue()` here. `redColor` does not have new/copy/... in its name, so it returns an unretained object.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I was a bit nervous about that part.